# Send data from module to script

Tags: python, irc, python-module

im creating an IRCbot module for people who are not that advanced to python.

But now im accurring a problem.
the module has this:

```
while 1:
    text=irc.recv(4096)
```

but is there a way to send "text" back to the script so i can use module.find or something

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: i want the module to send the string to the script, so the script can do something with it

Comment: Yes, that much was clear. What script are you talking about? And by "the module" do you mean the code you are writing?

Comment: yes im wrinting the module, and the script im talking about is the script wich uses `import IRCbot`

Comment: And what do you mean by sending text back into the script? Do you want to make the results you recv visible to the users of your module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly . . .

You users will probably need to define a callback. Your module will look like this:

```
user_callback = None

def register_callback(callback):
    global user_callback
    user_callback = callback

def main():
    while 1:
        text=irc.recv(4096)
        user_callback(text)
```